# Change remote glassfish server port in Netbeans 7.3

Tags: netbeans, glassfish, port, run-configuration

how can I change the default port 8080 when creating a new remote server instance in Netbeans 7.3?

The common way to change this for local glassfish instances is to edit the domain.xml file. But this doesn't work for remote instances. I even changed the local glassfish domain.xml file to use another port than 8080. This affects local glassfish server instances in Netbeans but not remote ones.

Any help would be appreciative.

Answer (score 8):

If GlassFish and Oracle Database are installed in the same system, it results in port conflict as both of them use port 8080.
Here is the procedure to change port number of GlassFish so that you can run GlassFish at a different port number from Oracle to avoid the port conflict.

1. Find out the folder where GlassFish is installed*.
   If you installed GlassFish along with NetBeans, you can find out the folder where GlassFish is installed by using the following procedure.

   - Select Services window by using **Window -> Services** in NetBeans IDE
   - Expand **Servers** node and select GlassFish Domain
   - Right click and select **Properties** option from popup menu
   - On the right of Domains Folder you can see the folder where GlassFish is installed. For example : C:\netbeans6.8\glassfish-v3\glassfish\domains You can also see the other details regarding Glassfish such as port number, in the same window.

2.Go to the folder where Glassfish in installed.

3.Go into config folder which is as follows (yours might be different): **c:\netbeans6.8\glassfish-3\glassfish\domains\domain1\config**

4.Open **domain.xml** using any text editor.

5.Look for 8080 and change it to some other port number that doesn’t conflict with other port numbers. I generally change it to 9999.

6.Save domain.xml.
7.Now you need to remove GlassFish from NetBeans and add it again so that NetBeans IDE understands the new port number. For this do the following:

- In Servers window of NetBeans, remove GlassFish by using RemoveServer button after selecting GlassFish server
- Click on AddServer and select GlassFish V2 or GlassFish V3 and click on Next
- Select the Installation Location of GlassFish and click on Next
- Accept defaults and click on Finish

8.Restart GlassFish, if it was already running.

> I got my source from a blog post you can find [here](http://www.srikanthtechnologies.com/blog/java/changeglassfishport.aspx).